# Does a Holy Weapon qualify for Litany of Righteousness?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

[Litany of Righteousness](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/litany-of-righteousness) says "If the target is evil, it takes double damage from attacks made by creatures with a good aura." It's on the Inquisitor spell list...but the inquisitor still needs a way to get the aura.

Holy Weapon says "This power makes the weapon good-aligned" and the Smiting Judgment says " At 6th level, the inquisitor’s weapons also count as one alignment type (chaotic, evil, good, or lawful) for the purpose of bypassing damage reduction."

Both of these talk about the weapon's aura not the creature's. Does that count for double damage?

If not, what are some other ways (e.g. spells or items) for an inquisitor to gain a Good aura?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Aura power is explained in a weird place, the [detect evil](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/detect-evil) spell (detect good references it). You gain an aligned aura by having a level of cleric or paladin, getting the undead or outsider subtype (like from being an aasimar) - or just being level 5+ in any class and being aligned (per the "creature with 5 or more HD" line)!  If the inquisitor is able to cast a third level spell, they likely already qualify as having a good aura.

Having an aligned weapon would not count; the spell is very specific about it being the creature.

Comment: Also, the spell as written specifies that the good aura has to come from a class feature (such as that of a paladin or cleric) or from having the (good) subtype.